# Как подключить org.apache.http.HttpEntity и т.п.? С 23 версии Sdk они не поддерживаются

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient

Как подключить org.apache.http.HttpEntity и т.п.?  С 23 версии Sdk они не поддерживаются.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если очень надо, то в конфиге gradle прописать:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```